# iPhone - Error setting up block that takes an array

Tags: iphone, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks

I am writing as a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938354/iphone-nsurlconnection-asynchronous-download-using-urls-in-nsarray) question I asked yesterday, but I have not heard back from the original responder. I would be happy to wait, but I have a small time limit. He helped me tremendously with my NSURLConnection code, and I understand perfectly how this is working, but I can't seem to get the syntax correct.

I can't get handler:^ to be recognized and this line:

```
[self loadImageArray:urlArray handler:^(NSMutableArray *)imageArray
```

and it needs to take an array (imageArray from loadImageArray) that is populated with images.

```
- (void)loadImageArray:(NSArray *)urls handler:(void(^)( handler)
```

This should populate an array (imageArray) asynchronously from the server.

How do I setup the block calls correctly? I have read about blocks on a few sites, but none of the suggestions have helped.

Again, I have asked the original responder, but have not heard back.

I hope that edit helps. Thank you!

Here is my .h

```
@interface OBNSURLViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSArray *jsonArray;
    NSMutableData *theJsonData;
    IBOutlet UIView *mainView;
    __weak IBOutlet UIImageView *mainImage;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *mainLabel;

}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSData *serverData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *mainScroll;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *imageArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *urlArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *imageData;
@end
```

Here is the relavent code I am stuck on:

```
- (void)parseJSONAndGetImages:(NSData *)data
{
    //initialize urlArray
    urlArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    //parse JSON and load into jsonArray
    jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:theJsonData options:nil error:nil];
    //assertion?
    assert([jsonArray isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]);

    //Make into one liner with KVC.... Find out what KVC is

    //Code to load url's into array goes here....

    //load the images into scrollview after fetching from server
    [self loadImageArray:urlArray handler:^(NSMutableArray *)imageArray //Here is a big problem area
     {
         //work goes here....
     }];
}

- (void)loadImageArray:(NSArray *)urls handler:(void(^)( handler)//This does not want to work either. I am stuck on handler???
{ dispatch_async(0, ^{
        //imageArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int y = 0; y < urlArray.count; y++)
        {
            //stuff goes here.....a
    });
        dispatch_async(dispath_get_main_queue(),^{
            handler(imageArray);
        });

}
```

Comment: Please don't abuse the `xcode` tag. Unrelated.

Comment: To get good answers you need to ask good questions. This question is vague and you're expecting us to debug your code? Break your problem down to a single question, and don't post more code than you need to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Still not clear enough-- is your handler block supposed to take an NSMutableArray as an argument or not? You have conflicting code and it's not obvious which one you want.

Comment: I don't know how to answer that, because I am confused about that myself...Does handler get setup in -(void)loadImageArray?

Comment: added more information, but I am struggling to explain this better. I am going through it again.

Comment: To answer your question Tom- Yes, It needs to take the array from loadImageArray so it can load the images into the SrollView

Comment: i have edited the question again to tray and make it more clear. Thank you all and I am sorry for the vagueness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I'm reading this, the method syntax should look like the following. If the handler block takes an argument, you need to declare that it does.

```
- (void)loadImageArray:(NSArray *)urls handler:(void (^)(NSMutableArray *imageArray))handler
{
    NSMutableArray *imageArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    // Do something with the urls array to fill in entries in imageArray...

    handler(imageArray);
}
```

You would call the method like this:

```
NSArray *urls = // filled in somewhere else...
[myObject loadImageArray:urls handler:^(NSArray *imageArray) { 
    NSLog(@"%@", imageArray); 
}];
```

Comment: Thank you!!! That makes a lot more sense.... and I don't know why I just could not see that before. I apologize for the question asking issues. Thanks again.